# error when i use cy.xpath inside cy.origin

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, element, xpath-2.0, cypress-origin

I'm using Cypress to test a website.

When I use xpath inside cy.origin(), It's not working.

```
it('t1', function() {
    cy.origin(('BaseUrl'), () => {
        cy.visit('/profile')
        cy.xpath("//input[@name='username']").type('user')
        cy.xpath("//input[@name='password']").type('pass')
        cy.xpath("//button[@type='button']").click()
    })
})
```

Error:

```
TypeError
cy.xpath is not a function
```

**`Note that it works correctly outside cy.origin()`**

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR:** Stick with standard Cypress commands inside `cy.origin()`.

It's a current limitation of `cy.orgin()`, in fact any custom command must be treated specially and `cy.xpath()` is a custom command.

See [Callback restrictions](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/origin#Callback-restrictions)

> It is also currently not possible to use **require()** or dynamic import() within the callback. Because of this limitation, it cannot use npm packages or other third-party libraries inside the callback, as there is no mechanism to reference them. **This functionality will be provided in a future version of Cypress.**
>
> While third-party packages are strictly unavailable, it is possible to reuse your own code between cy.origin() callbacks. The workaround is to create a custom Cypress command within the secondary origin in a before block:

```js
before(() => {
  cy.origin('somesite.com', () => {
    Cypress.Commands.add('clickLink', (label) => {
      cy.get('a').contains(label).click()
    })
  })
})

it('clicks the secondary origin link', () => {
  cy.origin('somesite.com', () => {
    cy.visit('/page')
    cy.clickLink('Click Me')
  })
})
```

But you can't use this pattern with `cy.xpath()` as you currently need to `require('cypress-xpath')` and that can't be done inside `cy.origin()`.

---

**A Workaround**

1. Navigate to `/node_modules/cypress-xpath/src/index.js`
2. Copy the entire contents
3. Add a new command file in support: `/cypress/support/xpath.js`
4. Add this to the file, pasting in the copied code

   ```js
   before(() => {
     cy.origin('somesite.com', () => {  // your cross-origin URL here

        // paste here code from /node_modules/cypress-xpath/src/index.js

     })
   })
   ```
5. Import `xpath.js` into `/cypress/support/commands.js`

Now `cy.xpath()` will work within `cy.orgin()` in any of your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if non-xpath works.

```js
cy.origin(('BaseUrl'), () => {
  cy.visit('/profile')
  cy.get("input[@name='username']").type('user')
  ...
```

If not, you've probably not set the `experimentalSessionAndOrigin` flag correctly.

Comment: Non-xpath works correctly, and I'm set xperimentalSessionAndOrigin in cypress.json as the following:                                                                                
       {
    "experimentalSessionAndOrigin": true
  }